# Problem with ionic entry

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I redirect, it says Page not found. what is wrong with my ionic Entry ?? Plz help thnx

code behind

```
Response.Redirect(my site's url + "editques/" + "QuesID/" + QuesID + "/" + PID + "/" +QuesTypeID);



ionic entry 

RewriteRule ^/myweb/edit/$ /myweb/Edit.aspx [I]
RewriteRule ^/myweb/edit/PID/([^/]*)$ /myweb/Edit.aspx?PID=$1 [I]
RewriteRule ^/myweb/edit/QuesID([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /myweb/Edit.aspx?QuesID=$1&PID=$2&QuesTypeID=$3 [I]
```

This ionic entry syntax always confuses me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what Ionic is, and no way of knowing what a valid URI on your site is or is not, but I would guess you're missing a slash immediately after "QuesID" on the last line:

You have:

```
..../myweb/editques/QuesID([^/]*)/....
```

I think you want:

```
..../myweb/editques/QuesID/([^/]*)/....
```

As a regex expression (?) it certainly doesn't match your format in the redirect.

Comment: @Serenity: if it didn't worked, why you marked the question as answered?

Comment: it didn't at that time..when I rechecked, it was some symbol missing only so ur answer did help :)